# Using ros package for filepaths

Tags: ros-kinetic, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I came across this method for loading files in a ros node. In this particular instance the file was a calibration yaml file like so:

```
ci_manager->loadCameraInfo("package://camera_drivers/resource/calibration/2017_12_101.yaml");
```

Where does the package:// command search for? How can I add other packages to this list?

Thank you.

edit: I found this other method of potentially doing the same thing?
http://wiki.ros.org/Packages#C.2B-.2B-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308664/using-ros-package-for-filepaths/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2018-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I came across this method for loading files in a ros node. In this particular instance the file was a calibration yaml file like so:

> ```
> ci_manager->loadCameraInfo("package://camera_drivers/resource/calibration/2017_12_101.yaml");
> ```

> Where does the package:// command search for?

This is not a command, it's a *protocol*, which makes `package://....` a form of URI.

In the end, such URIs can be used with packages such as [resource_retriever](http://wiki.ros.org/resource_retriever):

> This package retrieves data from url-format files such as `http://`, `ftp://`, `package://` `file://`, etc., and loads the data into memory. The `package://` url for ros packages is translated into a local `file://` url. The resourse retriever was initially designed to load mesh files into memory, but it can be used for any type of data. The resource retriever is based on the the libcurl library.

Other packages in ROS also support this.

> How can I add other packages to this list?

There is no specific list for this: all packages on the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` are considered when parsing these URIs.

So any ROS package in your Catkin workspace, packages in underlay workspaces and packages in the regular `/opt/ros/..` locations will be considered.

---

Edit: it seems this functionality was implemented in `camera_info_manager` in a slightly different way, see [these lines](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/blob/f9e705aac2218f0ba97fd029e9d7ba709d17dae4/camera_info_manager/src/camera_info_manager.cpp#L210-L256) for instance.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2018-11-16**:
Thanks, that helps! Quick clarification, if I have my package location on `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` but am not using catkin, just plain cmake. What then makes it a "ros package"? Or can it still be found using `package://` without catkin?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-16**:
Any directory with a `package.xml` is considered a ROS package.

Note though: the further you try to "stray" from the regular ROS pkg layout and conventions, the more tools will start to break.